# No way to improve edit after initially choosing accept/reject

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I like the addition of the "Improve" button in the review edits page. However, sometimes I only think of improving a post after choosing to accept/reject. Currently there is no way to do this other than waiting for the edit to be accepted/rejected and when there are <5 edits in the queue this can take a while.

Is there a workaround for this, or can this be added?

Comment: Yes, this is a problem. Another example: I voted to reject a trivial edit, [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20993/how-toggle-company-mode-with-prefix). Later I wanted to edit the question to remove an inappropriate tag (`elisp`). I fell into the same gotcha. Had I noticed the tag when I reviewed the edit, I would have removed it then. Too late. Now I'll forget to come back after the review is ended and remove the tag...

Answer (score 12):

You can still edit by visiting the edit link manually: `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12345/edit`. As I write, this starts from the suggested version, but will [merge the suggestion with your edit, reject the suggestion and not credit the suggester](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262314/edits-that-shadow-a-suggested-edit-inconsistently-reject-but-include-the-suggest). Use with care.

To merge the suggestion with your edit while **accepting** the suggestion, append `?improve=true` as in `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12345/edit?improve=true`.

Comment: That doesn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748645/devexpress-extra-tree-list-focus-node-retruns-old-value/edit?improve=true

Comment: @assylias What doesn't work for you? The URL in your comment isn't like either of the URLs in my answer.

Comment: I had appended `/edit?improve=true` to a question - I got it now - thanks.

Comment: I just tried this with id `35603222`. It redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35603222 and says "You have already reviewed this item". I don't see a way to improve the edit. Has this feature gone away in the past 12 years?

Answer (score -7):

Right now this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

If it is a worthwhile post, I am sure it will be voted upon pretty fast, otherwise, bring it up in SE chat.

Comment: Bring up in chat?? Really?

Comment: Do you know how old this answer is @ShadowWizard? ;-P