# Why vote for suggested-edits when you can edit yourself?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Example case:

1. Browse Stack Overflow to answer questions
2. Open a question and see it is badly formatted
3. See a suggested-edit already alleviating the formatting issue
4. Accepting the suggested edit
5. Back to the question, it still looks badly formatted...

Since I have edit permissions it seems pointless for me to add accept suggested edits (which won't be applied immediately) when I can simply edit the question myself.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: yes, I mean approve/reject. The main issue here is that I'm trying to make questions readable so I can answer them. If someone else already tried that I just want to apply those changes so I don't have to look at a horribly formatted question.

Comment: I always thought editing is harder than voting; but I see your point.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M: when looking at the suggested edits dashboard, I agree. When you are looking at a question anyhow you're usually (or at least I am) more thorough in looking at the edit anyhow.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ they say that one can *accept/reject* and *edit* and change something trivial (like an space) so that their **one** vote applies to the suggested edit, rather than just *approving/rejecting* so that there'll be a need for others to "vote".

Comment: Related/dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119232/why-cant-i-edit-a-question-answer-after-i-voted-approve-in-review-suggested-edi

Answer (score 8):

Well, that is part of the system. Approving is not the same as editing, and a single vote (unless from OP or a mod) isn't enough to get the suggested edit approved.

You have the option though to improve the suggested edit, which will approve it and gives you the possibility to edit it the same time. If you have something to add, choose this option when reviewing a suggested edit.

Until an edit is approved, you can't see it. There was a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131417) already that proposes to show the suggested edit once accepted.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will try the edit option for the time being (at least until the feature request has been applied). Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Don't use edit unless you really want to edit something. I am searching for the feature request but can't find it now.

Comment: Ok, in that case the question can't be answered yet it seems. Ideally I think there should be a difference between accepting edits for questions you are just browsing through versus accepting edits through the edit queue. Imho those should just be accepted anyhow. I can't seem to find the feature request either, I've looked through about 50 feature-requests concerning suggested-edits and nothing yet :(

Comment: @Pat this what you were talking about? [Show the edited form of the question when I've approved it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131417/260841)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yes, that is the one. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that would solve the problem a bit. Thinking about it though, perhaps cosmetic/formatting changes should just be a more lenient with voting requirements. If the only changes are whitespace and the adding of code tags there is no real change to the content anyhow.

Comment: @Wolph: Please do not make it easier for edit suggesters to spread [Lyme disease](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290934/4099598)....

Comment: @nathan: fun name but irrelevant to the discussion imho. If it improves the readability of the question it is a good edit, otherwise it is not.

Comment: @Wolph: The name describes the epidemic of terrible edits that do nothing but add back ticks where they don't belong. Those don't change the content, but they should not be *one iota* easier to approve than they already are.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: so it's not a good edit and shouldn't be accepted. Not sure if there's any point/score incentive to accept answers but if there is, perhaps that should be disabled for these type of questions. Right now I apparently only have the option to edit the question myself, effectively repeating the work someone else already did which is a larger problem than the backtick madness.