# What to do when a reviewer rejects and edits with your suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

Earlier today I suggested an edit to a question which I felt improved the formatting and increased the readability of the post.

[image]

It was rejected and edited by the reviewer with the same suggestions (as given by me):

[image]

I feel this is unfair as I was the one to suggest the edit. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: It looks like the post was also rejected by *community*. Have a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993/375663) post as to what happens in such a case

Comment: Please see this post for what happens when "reject and edit" is made by reviewer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work?rq=1

Comment: Not *exactly* the same; the applied edit *does* use different formatting for the first code block than you had suggested.

Comment: @goldPseudo True its not 'technically' the same but the end result is.

Comment: The issue [that was resolved here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355831/51) may have been at fault in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is unfair when the reviewer has rejected your edit and done the exactly same edit you have proposed.

This can be resolved through the following steps.

1. *We all make mistakes*. The user might have clicked "Reject and edit" and didn't know what to do in the next step. It happens sometimes with users to whom review queue is new. To make sure, first ping that user in a chat room or in the comments directly with "@editor name" to ask if it happened by mistake or whether it was intentional. Ask them to click "improve" if they were going to copy your edits.
2. Flag the post for a moderator attention (as a last resort) if the reviewer has not done anything but reapplied your edit. Moderators can approve the edit even though it was rejected in the suggested edit review. Moderators will also keep an eye on the edits queue if there is a pattern of such behaviour.

If it is still rejected, a meta post on respective per site meta would be good.

Comment: Two things: no need for a chatroom - editors can be addressed directly by an @-ping in a comment, and authors *cannot* override edit suggestion decisions if a subsequent edit has been made to the post.

Comment: @Shog9 Noted and edited. But I was in an impression that comments are not for discussion? So, I recommended chat.

Comment: Comments are a side channel for the post, @nog - there's no need for a conversation, just "hey \@editorname, please click improve if you're gonna use most of my changes."