# Review suspensions prevent authors from editing their own posts that have pending suggested edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I've answered [this question a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726892/how-to-deploy-my-website-with-one-click-using-git-bash-on-windows-and-a-scripted/63740971#63740971), unfortunately I've left a stupid typo. Therefore, I wish to edit my answer; however, this doesn't seem possible?

---

I've received a review suspension:

> You’ve been suspended from reviewing. You will be able to review again on Nov 7 at 1:11.

However, this does not restrict me from editing my other answers, as I can prove by trying to edit an old answer.

---

The answer in question has an edit that still needs approval.

[image: The edit link indicates that 1 edit is pending.]

Pressing the 'edit' button shows a popup without any real actions (due to the suspension).

---

Why can't I edit my own question? Should I wait until someone else accepts/rejects the suggested edit?

Comment: Do you agree with the edit? I can put one approve on it if you like.

Comment: The suggested edit is by the OP, removing the typo, so yea, please approve it ;)
However, still quite curious about why I can't edit my own answer!

Comment: Since I'm new to meta, could the silent down-voter please clarify how I should improve my question?

Answer (score 15):

As a workaround, you can manually open the edit page by navigating to

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/[POST ID]/edit
```

(so in your case, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63740971/edit) and edit the post yourself from the current revision. This will have the side effect of rejecting the suggested edit.

Comment: Great workaround! However, the only edit I wish to make, is the suggested edit. Using your link-workaround, and saving the edit shows: **Your changes are identical to a pending edit, please review it.** which leads to the same edit screen.

Comment: This answer no longer works following [these changes to the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355831/377214). Specifically, when loading the `/posts/[post ID]/edit` page, there's now a server-side check to see if there's a pending suggested edit, and if there is, it will redirect to that review item instead.